# Is it secure to display/embed user_id that represents each user from the db in the html of a page?

Tags: sql, database, basic-authentication, software-design

If I display user_id that represents each unique user in the db as an atrribute in an HTML element, is that good practice? Because I need the reference to the user if I want to perform an action on that particular user such as adding him to be my friend.

Example in HTML:

```html
<div data-user-id='12' onclick=addFriend(12)>
    Click to add John as your friend
</div>
```

Where 12 is John's actual user id in the db. From a security perspective, is it secure to do this?

Answer (score 0):

it's never a problem to display the user id, actually, it's more secure than showing the username which could be used for logins, but a better solution is to display an id that could be set or changed by the user himself, look for facebook design for reference.

In this case, you want the user to be able to set his public id, and you use this public id to identify the user externally, then you map it to the actual user id internally in the back end.

anyway, all of this is not relevant for an abstract case, to decide how secure it's you need to consider the other security design elements of your application, the main question is always what can a malicious user do by knowing the actual user id?

Answer (score 0):

As usual....it's complicated.

It all depends on how attractive your site is to hackers (and therefore how much effort they're going to invest), and how secure the rest of your solution is.

The first step in an organized attack is to find out as much as possible about your website. Your current solution leaks information. Knowing that users are identified by an integer may be useful (some database engines are more likely to use integers rather than GUIDs). It may help attackers guess other keys. By guessing sequential user IDs, they can find out how many users you have.

Once the attacker has found out all this information, they will use it to try and penetrate your application. The more information they have, the easier it is to create a plan. An individual piece of information may not be useful, but when you put it together with other snippets, it may reveal something useful.

So, no, there's no obvious major risk in this design by itself. It may be part of a wider attack, though, and it could be the bit of information that exposes some other flaw.